# Search for many strings in a single document

Tags: search, lucene, full-text-search

I have a list of 1M to 10M strings and I want to see which ones of them can be found in a single document (say 1 page of text).

I know I can use Lucene (Solr/Elasticsearch) to find all documents containing a string. But this is the opposite.

I could program some ad-hoc solution based on one of the string-searching algorithms such as [Aho-Corasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm), tries, etc., but I assume I would be reinventing the wheel. Is there any library/framework for this?

(I am fine with splitting the strings and the documents into words, if it makes any difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This use case is usually solved by a "Percolator" component .
Both Apache Solr[1] and Elasticsearch[2] offer the functionality.
Basically you index the "queries" **Q** and then build a query **D** out of a document to verify which queries Q match.

[1] https://github.com/flaxsearch/luwak , http://www.flax.co.uk/what-we-do/luwak/

[2] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html